# Как правильно передать параметр в URL

Tags: url, php, get

открываю таккую ссылку:

```
 mysite.ru?id=Source%5c001
```

делаю вывод в скрипте значение id,
результат:

```
Source\\001
```

Как передать значение, так чтобы скрипт получил значение так как есть? То есть если я сделаю вывод в скрипте, должно получится:

```
Source%5c001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
mysite.ru?id=Source%255c001
```

Если сылка формируется скриптом, то, соответственно:

```
echo urlencode('Source%5c001');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
urlencode($string);
```

Может не то, просто не совсем понял зачем это.

Comment: Не помогла эта функция. Проблема в том, что я передаю вышеуказанное значение переменной id, а в скрипте это значение передается дальше в другой скрипт по средством curl. Соответсвенно, тот скрипт, к которому обращается curl, должен получить id=Source%5c001, а не id=Source\\\001